# Is there any performance or any other drawback of using ContentEditable HTML tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm bound to use `<p>` tag with [content editable](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_contenteditable), because I'm unable to style `<textarea>` as desired.

> Are there any known drawbacks of content editable, in terms of performance or any other criteria?

Comment: What is stopping you from using the textarea? The only downside I can see is it being much hard to use a `p` tag in a form.

Comment: For performance, not much difference. For accessibility, not recommended.

Comment: @HaoWu Can you expand on performance?

Comment: @Kobe I think of course it will be slower than `textarea` since the box model needs to be recalculated, but maybe not that critical.

Comment: I'm not sure using a <p> is a good idea. If the user pastes some HTML formatted text in there, you can end up with invalid HTML (divs, tables etc in the p). Using a div would be much better.